# Vue 3 and Tailwind,Can't make an animation work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, tailwind-css

I have a basic nav header and I am trying to make it reactive,when I click on the "show menu" button I don't get an animation,but when I close the menu I get one.I am still kinda new to this and I don't know how to fix it.I tried to make the enter seperate but it didn't work.

Template

```
<template>
  <div class="flex justify-center">
    <header
      class="p-5 shadow-md bg-white rounded-full mt-6 md:flex md:items-center md:justify-between"
    >
      <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
        <span
          class="text-3xl cursor-pointer mx-2 md:hidden block"
          @click="toggleMobileMenu"
        >
        </span>
      </div>
      <ul class="hidden md:flex">
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500 focus:text-cyan-500"
            >HOME</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500 focus:text-cyan-500"
            >SERVICE</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500 focus:text-cyan-500"
            >ABOUT</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500 focus:text-cyan-500"
            >CONTACT</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500 focus:text-cyan-500"
            >BLOG'S</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>

      <!--Phone-->
      <input
        @click="toggleLinksVisibility"
        type="checkbox"
        role="button"
        aria-label="Display the menu"
        class="menu md:hidden mt-1"
      />
      <transition name="fade-slide">

      <ul
        v-if="mobileMenuOpen || linksVisible"
        class="rounded-lg md:flex md:items-center z-10 md:z-auto md:static absolute bg-white w-full left-0 md:w-auto py-2 pl-9 md:opacity-100 md:rounded-none md:mt-0 mt-8"
      >
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl focus:text-cyan-500 hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500"
            >HOME</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl focus:text-cyan-500 hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500"
            >SERVICE</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl focus:text-cyan-500 hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500"
            >ABOUT</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl focus:text-cyan-500 hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500"
            >CONTACT</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="mx-4 my-6 md:my-0">
          <a
            href="#"
            class="text-xl focus:text-cyan-500 hover:text-cyan-500 duration-500"
            >BLOG'S</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
      </transition>
    </header>
  </div>
```

script

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onBeforeUnmount, onMounted, ref } from "vue";

const mobileMenuOpen = ref<boolean>(false);
const linksVisible = ref<boolean>(false);

function toggleMobileMenu(): void {
  mobileMenuOpen.value = !mobileMenuOpen.value;
}
function toggleLinksVisibility(): void {
  linksVisible.value = !linksVisible.value;
}

function closeLinksOnResize() {
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    linksVisible.value = false;
  }
}

onMounted(() => {
  window.addEventListener("resize", closeLinksOnResize);
});

onBeforeUnmount(() => {
  window.removeEventListener("resize", closeLinksOnResize);
});
</script>
```

style

```
<style scoped>
.fade-slide-enter-active,
.fade-slide-leave-active {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in, opacity 0.3s ease-in;
}

.fade-slide-enter,
.fade-slide-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50px); /* Initial state */
}

.menu {
  --s: 30px; /* control the size */
  --c: black; /* the color */

  height: var(--s);
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-inline: calc(var(--s) / 2) solid #0000;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  --_g1: linear-gradient(var(--c) 20%, #0000 0 80%, var(--c) 0) no-repeat
    content-box border-box;
  --_g2: radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 50% 12.5%, var(--c) 95%, #0000)
    repeat-y content-box border-box;
  background: var(--_g2) left var(--_p, 0px) top,
    var(--_g1) left calc(var(--s) / 10 + var(--_p, 0px)) top,
    var(--_g2) right var(--_p, 0px) top,
    var(--_g1) right calc(var(--s) / 10 + var(--_p, 0px)) top;
  background-size: 20% 80%, 40% 100%;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: inset(0 25%);
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(90deg, #0000, #000 25% 75%, #0000);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-position 0.3s var(--_s, 0.3s),
    clip-path 0s var(--_s, 0.6s);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: var(--s);
  inset: 40% 0;
  background: var(--c);
  transition: transform 0.3s calc(0.3s - var(--_s, 0.3s));
}

.menu:checked {
  clip-path: inset(0);
  --_p: calc(-1 * var(--s));
  --_s: 0s;
}
.menu:checked:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu:checked:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu:focus-visible {
  clip-path: none;
  -webkit-mask: none;
  border: none;
  outline: 2px solid var(--c);
  outline-offset: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Also If you can tell me if my component is okay and if it's not how I can refactor it because I am new.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-form` at `.fade-slide-enter`.
Also using tailwindcss and then just writing entire css blocks isnt really the idea of tailwind and if you want to prevent multiple same html, like you list elements you could just place a v-for on them.